# Cocos2d-x C++ build error on Eclipse ADT

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, eclipse-adt

I'm newbie of Cocos2d-x C++. I tried to run then debug the sample code HelloCpp of cocos2d-x 2.2.1 on my Mac. The following is what I did:

1 . Set environment variables: NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION, NDK_ROOT, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT, COCOS2DX_ROOT, ...

I can run build_native.sh from Terminal without errors.

2 . Add C++ classes to project

HelloCpp is a C++ project already so I ignored converting this project to C/C++ project in Eclipse.

C++ classes added to project successfully.

3 . Change the project settings to specify how to run make command

```
In My project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Builder Setting:
   Set "Build command" = /bin/bash ${ProjDirPath}/build_native.sh NDK_DEBUG=1 V=1

In My project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Builder Setting -> Tool Chain Editor:
   Set "Current toolchain" = Android GCC
   Set "Current builder" = Gnu Make Builder
```

4 . Run project as an Android Application. I got these errors:

```
.../cocos2d-x-2.2.1/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh: line 68: mkdir: command not found

.../ADT/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/android-ndk-r9b//ndk-build: line 40: dirname: command not found

.../cocos2d-x-2.2.1/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh: line 33: dirname: command not found

.../cocos2d-x-2.2.1/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/build_native.sh: line 52: dirname: command not found

.../ADT/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130917/android-ndk-r9b//ndk-build: line 132: uname: command not found
```

I searched a lot but cannot resolved errors. I was wrong somewhere. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've listed all the possibilities to cause error while building cocos2d-x in eclipse [here in my blog](http://deepakgautam.com.np/2013/11/16/building-cocos2d-x-project-in-eclipse/). Hope it helps you. Let me know if it still doesn't fix your issue.

Comment: Hi dg_no_9. I appreciate your guide. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure. Could you please vote up, if it did answer your question? :)

Comment: I can run but debug. I set break points but they was not reached. Can you help please?

Comment: I'm using eclipse just to build and run on Android, so I have no experience about debugging C++ application in eclipse. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_debug_cocos2d-x_games Here are some steps, you may find some solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `README.md` document in 'yourproject/proj.android' folder, it will help you build your project in eclipse.

Comment: Thank you Omega.yue. I missed that important file :)