# Build Cocos2D-X 3.0 game on Eclipse (works on command line)

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have been able to make a simple HelloWorld and the CPPTests to work on an iOS simulator, iOS iPhone4, Mac and Samsung Galaxy S4 following the new 3.0 command line documentation:

### How to start a new game

1. Download the code from [cocos2d download site][4]
2. Run `setup.py`
3. Run the `cocos` script

Example:

```
$ cd cocos2d-x
$ ./setup.py
$ source FILE_TO_SAVE_SYSTEM_VARIABLE
$ cocos new MyGame -p com.your_company.mygame -l cpp -d /home
$ cd /home/MyGame
```

#### Build and run new project for android

```
$ cocos run -p android
```

#### Build and run new project for iOS

```
$ cocos run -p ios
```

#### Build and run new project for OSX

```
$ cocos run -p mac
```

But when I have tried to open and build with Eclipse (ADT version and completely updated Android NDK, ADT, etc.)

NOTE: I have opened and updated the Eclipse project settings following the instructions from here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started and here [Cocos2d-x C++ build error on Eclipse ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345192/cocos2d-x-c-build-error-on-eclipse-adt) but those are outdated and for Cocos2D-x 2.x version so do not work.

Someone has been able to make work Eclipse with Cocos2D-X 3.0 new version???

Attached are the command line success logs and the screenshot errors from Eclipse.

**Command Line Works:**
[image: command line works]

**Eclipse Errors:**
[image: eclipse errors to build]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to link your project to the libCocos2dx.

I recommend this tutorial to setup your first project with Cocos2d-x v3.0+ : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Build_an_Android_Project_with_Eclipse

Answer (score -1):

What I do is first create the project and build it using command line then import the project in Eclipse. After that I enable CDT for the project after that everything works fine for me.